# Port Forwarding from VPN VM to All Other VMs in its Subnet

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, port-forwarding, proxmox

I'm using proxmox hypervisor to setup a ubuntu VPN VM (Mullvad VPN) that effectively acts as gateway for all other VMs. Here is my setup illustrated:

[image]

In VPN VM, I'm using these command to route the traffic between the vpn tunnel interface (`wg-mullvad` is the mullvad wireguard interface):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg-mullvad -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o wg-mullvad -j ACCEPT
```

At the moment everything seems to be working, running several of these iptables command to route my traffic so that I can SSH into the VM1 and VM2, as well as accessing the webserver on them across different subnet, originated from home network:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport 22221 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.201:22
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport 22222 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.202:22
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.201:80
```

However, I got an issue where port forwarding in VM1 and VM2 is not working. I have opened a port in the mullvad vpn service iteself following [this guide](https://mullvad.net/en/help/port-forwarding-and-mullvad/). I could verify that it's indeed working in VPN VM itself, but not on the subnet `192.168.1.0/24` (VM1 & VM2).

I thought that port forwarding should happens automatically in vpn tunnel, without requiring any additional settings on the VPN VM itself, am I wrong? Any idea how to properly handle this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Seems like running

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 58787 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.202:58787
```

works. Given my "special" setup of VPN VM (single NIC, routing VPN traffic), I'm not sure is this is the correct way to do it. Since I'm not very good with networking, will this cause any traffic leak from the VPN (for example, the traffic directly goes from `eth0` to `eth1` without going through `wg-mullvad`)?

Comment: fwiw, you can omit the `:58787` at the end of your working nat rule since the destination port is not mapped to a new port. So `--to-destination 192.168.1.202` should work fine.

Comment: `tcpdump` and `netcat` will be helpful in debugging this. Maybe attempt connecting and attach logs.